# Screen becomes black during a call

Tags: screen

I am also having this frustrating issue where, during any call dialed or incoming, the screen would completely go blank. Pressing the power button also doesn't do anything.

I have a newly purchased Nokia 5.3 and it was updated from android one to Android 10. The problem occurred one week after! Any help please! Noting that I’m not an Android expert!

Comment: The screen should only go black if you come close to the display (e.g. with your face). There should a proximity sensor which emits invisible light and your skin reflects it which is then detected by a special sensor. May be this proximity sensor is defect or do you use a special case that covers this sensor?

Comment: @Robert That's exactly what I thought at first too, but the OP states that pressing the power button doesn't help.